# Is there an AWS service like Amazon WorkMail but smaller?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-workmail

The case is:

I just need about 5 to 10 GB of storage and not 50 GB like WorkMail offers.

Hence my question: Is there an AWS service that I can use to send and receive emails with Outlook like WorkMail, but with less storage capacity?

Comment: Still cheaper than Gmail at $6/user/month.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no other AWS Service that would offer the same service will less storage.